# Intermittent Azure DevOps Access and Authorization Issue in Visual Studio and Azure Web App

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I'm encountering intermittent access issues with my Azure DevOps account in Visual Studio, as well as an authorization problem when connecting the same account to an Azure Web App. I would appreciate any insights or solutions to these problems.

Issue 1: Intermittent Access in Visual Studio

For the past few days, accessing my Azure DevOps account through Visual Studio has been inconsistent. Most of the time, I receive a message prompting me to reauthenticate my account. When reauthentication fails, I attempt to disconnect and reconnect my account to Visual Studio, but this solution is not always successful.

Issue 2: Authorization Error in Azure Web App

I am also trying to connect the same Azure DevOps account to an Azure Web App. In the Azure Web App's Deployment Center, when I try to set up the connection, I encounter the following error: "Failed to set up deployment. Failed to retrieve auth identity properties."

What I've Tried:

Reauthenticating my account in Visual Studio. Disconnecting and reconnecting my Azure DevOps account in Visual Studio.

Environment:

Visual Studio Pro 2022 Azure Services: Azure DevOps, Azure Web App Operating System: Windows 11

Questions:

What could be causing the intermittent access and reauthentication issues in Visual Studio with my Azure DevOps account?

How can I resolve the "failed to retrieve auth identity properties" error when connecting Azure DevOps to an Azure Web App?

Comment: Do you get any detailed error messages when failing to connect to Azure DevOps or Azure Web App? Are your Azure DevOps org and the Web App backed to the same tenant?

Comment: In Visual Studio i don't get a detailed error message, just the little yellow exclamation triangle next to my accounbt and a generic message telling me i need to reauthorize my credentials. 

In the Azure portal, when I try to connect the web app to my DevOps repo, i get the error message "failed to retrieve auth identity properties".

My Azure DevOps org and the Web App are on the same tenat, as I am using the same microsoft account. I have also tried connecting other DevOps accounts (different tenant) with the same result.

Comment: I've basically given up for now and I am deploying manually using FTP. Hopefully Microsoft will resolve the issue soon.

Comment: To post an update here:   From discussion on related [Microsoft Q&A thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1496244/error-when-trying-to-setup-up-ci-cd-with-bitbucket?page=4#answers) --Users setting up CI/CD integration  for App Service WebApp :"Failed to set up deployment. Failed to retrieve auth identity properties.  Our product engineering team rolled out a fix (on 1/16) to address this issue.